# Setting up a bind server and can't find the zone file

Tags: bind, centos5

I am trying to set up a bind server.  My named.conf file has the following lines

> ...
>   options{
>   ...
>   directory "/var/named";
>   ...
>   };
>   ...
>   zone "sly.net"{
>     type master;
>     file "data/db.sly.net";
>     };
>   ...

My file is at /var/named/data/db.sly.net - but when I try to start the server, I get the error

> > zone sly.net/IN: loading master file data/db.sly.net: file not found
> >     _default/sly.net/IN: file not found

I'm not sure what the issue could be. Is my file in the correct place?

Comment: Can you try to specify zone file location like `file "/var/named/data/db.sly.net";` http://www.garron.me/go2linux/how-setup-dns-server-master-slave-bind.html

Comment: @Suku I tried that, but it didn't work. Good idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

named may be running as a chroot program with lowered privs.....thus the location of /var/named virtually within the chroot environment may be different than the actual location in a non-chrooted environment.

Comment: I have other issues, but the correct location was /var/named/chroot/var/named/data instead of /var/named/data